# How can I change a column in repository.cs?

Tags: c#, json, typescript, slickgrid, serenity

I change the day value in the list by doing some calculations. But I can't show it in the list.
When I try as follows, I get the error customerId must be uniqueid. I would be happy if you help. I'm using an old version of Serenity. I'm trying to do what I show in the photo.

[image]

this is my repository.cs

```cs
public ListResponse List(IDbConnection connection, ListRequest request)
{
    List<dynamic> listeResmi = new List<dynamic>();
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        listeResmi = getAllTatilListe(connection);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    var row = new MyRow();
    var query = new SqlQuery().From(row).SelectTableFields();

    query.CountRecords = true;
    var entities = new List<MyRow>();

    ListResponse<MyRow> listReturn = new ListResponse<MyRow>();

    var totalCount = query.ForEach(connection, () =>  
    {
        var yeniGunFarki = GetDateRestriction(Convert.ToDateTime(row.VADE),listeResmi);
        row.GECIKME = Convert.ToInt32(yeniGunFarki);
        row.MUSTERIID = row.MUSTERIID;
        entities.Add(row);
    });

    listReturn.Entities =entities;
    listReturn.Skip = 0;
    listReturn.Take = 100;
    listReturn.TotalCount = totalCount;
    return listReturn;
}
```

It is my error json. There is MUSTERIID parameter.

> Uncaught Each data element must implement a unique 'MUSTERIID' property. Object at index '0' has repeated identity value '18839376296_94d31a01-0b3b-4720-8895-13f23dc6d714': {"InsertDate":"2023-07-19T12:59:38.353","MUSTERIID":"18839376296_94d31a01-0b3b-4720-8895-13f23dc6d714"}

[image]

Comment: Currently `row` is never assigned a new value, so `entities.Add(row)` will add the same object to the list multiple times. You probably want to make a copy of `row` (or similar) before adding it to `entities`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MyRow` is an [`IRow<TFields>`](https://serenity.is/docs/api/dotnet/Serenity.Net.Entity/Serenity.Data/IRow-1.md), then your `row` object should have a [`CloneRow`](https://serenity.is/docs/api/dotnet/Serenity.Net.Entity/Serenity.Data/IRow-1/CloneRow.md) method:

```
var totalCount = query.ForEach(connection, () =>  
{
    var newRow = row.CloneRow() as MyRow;

    var yeniGunFarki = GetDateRestriction(Convert.ToDateTime(newRow.VADE),listeResmi);
    newRow.GECIKME = Convert.ToInt32(yeniGunFarki);
    newRow.MUSTERIID = row.MUSTERIID; // Not sure why this line is here. I assume you can remove it
    entities.Add(newRow);
});
```

Now `entities` will contain unique objects and if each row already has a unique `MUSTERIID` so should the items in `entities`.

Comment: newRow.MUSTERIID = row.MUSTERIID;

I deleted this line, it was unnecessary as you said. When I try the code, I get errors in newRow.VADE and newRow.DELAY. "Row" does not contain a definition "VADE" and no accessible extension method... it continues like this.

Comment: I added new picture of my question's bottom about this solve.

Comment: @ŞebnemSeymen Ah, you probably need to cast `newRow` to your `MyRow` type: `row.CloneRow() as MyRow` (see my updated answer). However, I don't know your implementation of `MyRow` so this assumes that `CloneRow()` actually returns the correct type.

Comment: @ŞebnemSeymen That's great to hear! If you think my answer was the solution, then don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).